# How to save a video in SQLite databse?

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite, ubuntu-16.04

I've a written a simple code in `Qt` using `OpenCV`which records live video from webcam and saves it in `.avi` file format. I want to know if there's any way to store the same video in `SQLite` database.

Comment: store the video in a directory then save the video file path in the database

Comment: Don't. Databases are designed to hold structured data, not huge binary streams. Store your video files on a normal filesystem in a consistent fashion (e.g. use a hash for the filenames) and store references to those files in your database.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to store video content in SQLite database (not the video path)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54707299/how-to-store-video-content-in-sqlite-database-not-the-video-path)

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use the [blob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625029/how-do-i-store-and-retrieve-a-blob-from-sqlite) datatype - but a DB isn't the place to store such large datafiles. Stick the video on disk and put where the file is located in your DB. You'll find accessing it later is a lot easier 9as all the OS operations for streaming expect to find a file on disk to work with).